# File-Search in Gnome-Shell no longer working

Tags: gnome, nautilus, search

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3.28.2.
Until recently, I could search for files located in my home-folder using the GNOME-Shell by just pressing the SUPER-key and typing the name of the file. But for some reason, I no longer get any search results for files. Only when I open Nautilus and carry out the search there. All other searches like calculator, weather or contacts work well.

When I open Settings->Search, everything is activated, but "Files" does not show up. However, by clicking on the little cog-symbol, I can see that all my folders inside my home-folder are enabled for search.

I'd be very happy if somebody were able to help me fix this problem! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When did this occur have you checked your logs open a terminal ——.      cd /var/log/    ls -ll